# How to get the page id when user removed my application from page

Tags: php, facebook

Am new to facebook application.

Basically i want to be notify when some one removed my application from his page.

using application > advanced > Deauthorize Callback: URl. i can able to receive signed_request.
But i needs to know the page id which page user has removed my application.
Since in my application user can add my app to multiple pages of his account. 
so when he remove my app from any one of that page. i needs to know the page id.

looking forward to hear from your answers in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible just with "Deauthorize Callback". However, you can save current page id to your database and when your application have received this callback you'll have an idea what page what the last one.

Hope that helps.

Comment: you meant to store the page id when users who are in my apps installed page ?. suppose a user has installed my app in more than 3 of his pages. he navigating all of his three pages. and removing app from one of that page. how can i identify he was removed that page alone ?

Comment: I am not quite sure where are these three pages. I could find only one : `http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy&section=apps`